# Stop syncing photos from iphone, is it still saved on icloud.com?

Tags: icloud

I am using icloud photo library to sync my iphone photos to my macbook. Does it mean that all photos are stored and saved on icloud.

In other words If I stop syncing photos from iphone, will all photos on icloud.com be deleted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you sync your photos to iCloud , it will be automatically get stored in the iCloud drive. Once you stop syncing your phone with iCloud drive , the photos which you already synced will be there , those will not be deleted with user permission.